# Returning an object reference in a wrapped temporary

Tags: c++

I have an iterator to an internal contiguous memory block and when invoking the `operator *` I would like to wrap what ever the iterator is pointing into a class that marshals various operations that can be performed on the underlying type.

Here's an example to better explain myself.

```
class iterator
{
private:
    some_t* _ptr;

public:
// ..
wrapper<some_t&> operator *() { return wrapper<some_t&>(*_ptr); }
// ..
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
auto it = some_class.begin() // returns iterator above;

*it += 20; // do some operation that invokes the overload.

return 0;
}
```

I want to have the wrapper behave like the underlying built in type as much as possible (all the operators, binary, unary, Boolean, etc...) but the above has proven to be difficult to achieve and very messy, especially when I want to have `wrapper<some_t*>` and `wrapper<some_t&>` behave as the built in types would.

It's clear my approach is just plain wrong, so I was wondering if anyone else has any ideas on how to achieve the same goals but in a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: As of C++11 you can't yet overload `operator.`, but you can overload `operator->`, and that's what most iterators and smart pointers do.

Comment: As it turns out, I'm not concerned with the `operator.` , its mostly things like arithmetic and binary operators, and having the thing not break if I do something like;  `auto& ref = *it; ref += 10;`.  Essentially, something that behaves exactly like the usual `T&` reference that is returned by most iterators except it's actually a `wrapper<T&>` so I can override some of the operations I need.

Comment: How does `wrapper` look like ? Does it have some `operator T&` ?

Comment: It's not pretty by any means.. but take a look https://github.com/rtlayzell/libimg/blob/master/libimg/include/pixel.hpp

Comment: For usage, check out the `demo/main.cpp` and the `libimg/bitmap_iterator.hpp`

Comment: I could have just used `reinterpret_cast<some_t&>(&_ptr)` instead of a wrapper, if I didn't need the extra state or there was some other way of getting at it without storing it in `some_t` (the extra state being the format of a pixel used in the binary and arithmetic operations).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `std::ref()` ?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref

It's a function that returns a `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.  That type, in turn, has an implicit conversion to the bound reference type.

It isn't entirely what you're looking for, but it might be as close as you can get (and it's all ready to go).  With the implicit assignment you can pass it to another function that takes a parameter of the wrapped type, but it doesn't give you dot access to the methods on the underlying object.  AFAIK that's out.

Comment: Sorry, no, while occasionally useful I haven't a need for `std::ref()`